# Generate line hash scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, examples

I want to recreate the original NASA TLX Question from [here](http://humansystems.arc.nasa.gov/groups/TLX/downloads/TLXScale.pdf), but how do you generate the hash scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using TikZ

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.2cm, x=0.05* \textwidth,font=\sffamily]
    %axis
    \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (20,0);

    %ticks
    \foreach \x in {0}
        \draw (\x,0pt) -- (\x,15pt)
        node[anchor=south] {};

    \foreach \x in {1,...,9}
        \draw (\x,0pt) -- (\x,5pt)
        node[anchor=south] {};

    \foreach \x in {10}
        \draw (\x,0pt) -- (\x,15pt)
        node[anchor=south] {};

    \foreach \x in {11,...,19}
        \draw (\x,0pt) -- (\x,5pt)
        node[anchor=south] {};

    \foreach \x in {20}
        \draw (\x,0pt) -- (\x,15pt)
        node[anchor=south] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you categorized the question as tex-core I would refer you to the TeXbook Exercise 10.4, which demonstrates how to draw a ruler complete with ticks.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
\def\tick#1{\vrule height 0pt depth #1pt}
\def\\{\hbox to 1cm{\hfil\tick4\hfil\tick8}}
\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\tick8\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\}}
\end{document}
```

Other methods is to use the LaTeX `picture environment` or PGF/TikZ. The latter would probably be the easiest, but comes with a learning curve. Some amazing pure TeX rulers can also be found here http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=ruler developed by Victor Eijkhout.

Comment: To be honest, I was not sure how to categorize this question but this is a useful answer